# Spring data jpa query with set null gives ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to delete a column value, here's my query:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update TableA r set r.readDate= '' where r.id= :id")
void clearReadDate(@Param("id") String id);
```

But when I execute it I get:

> ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

How come?

The underlying SQL is also strange:

```
Hibernate: update SC.TABLEA cross join  set READ_DATE='' where ID=?
```

what is that cross join?

Comment: `update Entity`. Did you really named your entity `Entity` or am I missing something about Spring JPA and some kind of special `Entity` keyword ? Try to change the name of your class. Entity is probably a reserved word. 
A cross join is a cartesian product. More info here : https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php

Comment: Hi! It was just a name I made up on the moment but I updated the question

Comment: Sometimes, names matter. It can trigger bug like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use native query instead.

```
@Query("UPDATE TABLEA SET READ_DATE = ?1 WHERE ID = ?2", nativeQuery=true)
void clearReadDate(String date, String id);
```

Or you can use your variant with @Param annotation instead of ?1 and ?2

P.S. by default EntityManager won't flush any changes,to do that, use over @Query annotation:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true)
```